# Different storeviews (languages) with different url's not working

Tags: magento2.3, base-url, language-switcher

We have a **multilanguage store**, was working fine. Now we changed the URL for every language but now the switch is not working anymore. Not even changing the language anymore.

compile, cleaning cache, even setting to production is not working.

> www.koperenpannen.com / www.copperpans.store

Comment: Please describe the steps in your question, what you have done so far.

Comment: Created a store - 3 languages, that worked in www.koperenpannen.com languages etc worked everywhere. Then we changed the url for the english and german shop at base url. After that we did setup:upgrade, compile clean cache. That did not work (language switch keeps going back to the home page of the current language.) so set site in developer mode and then to production. Same result.

Comment: If I change manually (change the storeview code behind the url) it works. So it is something in the language/storeview switcher I think. But I can not find a resolution for it.

Comment: For URL change, you need to create 3 different stores (each having a single store view with a particular language). Only 1 store with 3 store view will not work in this case.

Comment: Just a store with it own storeview ? But then I am losing my language switcher. So for every store I need 3 storeviews too ? Is weird. You should think it must be possible. It is only because of adding the url it is not working anymore. Or should I hardcode the language switcher to the url it has to go too ?

Comment: You can set store labels as the names of languages. 3 stores (same label as language name) with each store having a single store view (language).

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, I change the store label to the name of the url, with 1 storeview (language) But I will lose the store/ language this way. How come this is not working ? I only change the base urls, if I set it back to the head base url, everything is working. It only needs to take over the url per language. But when looking for a resolution I found more people are having the same problemm, is weird